# word start with uppercase (unicode) in laravel validation

Tags: regex, laravel, laravel-5

I need check that word start from Uppercase (for name of user) and it should work in not only English language (first of all, in Russian).

Now I have next code:

```
$data_user  = $this->validate($request, [
    'name'=>'required|regex:/^[\p{Lu}][\p{Ll}]*$/',
]);
```

It's work as I want in this [service](http://www.rubular.com/) but it doesn't work in Laravel validation. How fix my code or we can't do it in laravel validation?

Comment: On what sample input it doesn't work?

Comment: Nothing wrong over here it works pretty well.

Comment: @revo 'Андрей' - doesn't work, 'Andrew' - work

Comment: Set `u` flag `/^\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*$/u`

Comment: @revo thank you very much, it work!